# Simpler way to split String from .txt file in Java

Tags: java, io, integer

Here is the code that I created. It works the way I wanted but I think it could have been simpler.

```
File test = new File("test.txt");

try{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(test);

    int[] testInt= new int[100];
    String[] test= new String[100];
    String[] print= new String[100];
    int i= 0;

    while(input.hasNextLine()){
        test[i] = input.nextLine();
        String[] temp = test[i].split(":");
        testInt[i] = Integer.parseInt(temp[1]);
        print[i] = temp[0];
        i++;
    }

    for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
        System.out.println(print[j] + ":" + testInt[j]);

} catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
    System.out.println("File not found!");
}
```

Here is the content of "test.txt":

```
Telur Dadar:40
Maggi Goreng:50
```

The desired output is similar to what's in `test.txt` except that the integer values are stored with int datatype. Somehow I think there's a way to do it using `nextInt()` and delimiters or something.
I've tried using `nextInt()` and some customer delimiters but all I got is a lot of errors.

Any suggestions how to do so?

Comment: Wouldn't such a question belong to CodeReview instead ?

Comment: I didn't know about CodeReview. I asked here because I've seen some questions here with similar purposes. So, should I remove this and post it over at CodeReview? I am really new here.

Comment: I think so (but I may be wrong). Your code is working, so technically it's rather a code review you need. CoreReview belongs to the same StackExchange family as StackOverflow. See : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: reword your question to be how do I avoid using arrays to do this... I will have a answer shortly just coding it for you

Comment: @OlivierCroisier This question is not off-topic for Stack Overflow. No reason to post it on Code Review.

Comment: @OlivierCroisier I see. I'll post it there next time. Thanks for introducing CodeReview to me.

Comment: @DanCiborowski-MSFT Oh, actually I'd like to use some of the arrays because I'd like to retrieve the values later to sort them or filter them. I forgot to add that details. I'll add it in the OP.

Comment: This can be done easier not in an array and instead using a map...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you start with a routine to count the number of matching lines with a regular expression. Also you should `close` a `Scanner` that's reading a file (so you don't leak file handles). The easiest is probably a [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and a pattern like "^\D+:\d+" which matches consecutive-alpha characters followed by a `:` and then consecutive digits like

```
public static int countLines(File f) {
    int c = 0;
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(f)) {
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = s.nextLine();
            if (line.matches("^\\D+:\\d+")) {
                c++;
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return c;
}
```

Then you can create a routine to populate your arrays (with your line `Scanner`) like

```
public static void readLines(File f, int[] nums, String[] vals) {
    int c = 0;
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(f)) {
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = s.nextLine();
            if (line.matches("^\\D+:\\d+")) {
                Scanner input = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter(":");
                vals[c] = input.next();
                nums[c] = input.nextInt();
                c++;
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Finally, your `main` method might look like (assuming `test.txt` is in the user's home folder) and I would also recommend formatted io with `printf` and renaming your variables `print` and `testInt` to `vals` and `nums` like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File test = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "test.txt");
    int lineCount = countLines(test);
    int[] nums = new int[lineCount];
    String[] vals = new String[lineCount];
    readLines(test, nums, vals);
    for (int j = 0; j < lineCount; j++) {
        System.out.printf("%s:%d%n", vals[j], nums[j]);
    }
}
```

I get

```
Telur Dadar:40
Maggi Goreng:50
```

Comment: I somehow couldn't use `printf` on my Eclipse IDE. Whenever I try to use it, it says **The method printf(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, int)**. Also many thanks for the code. I'm very new to Java (I guess I should have mentioned that) and what you wrote is very understandable for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using Java 8 features as follow

```
package example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class SplitFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("test.txt"))) {
            stream.forEach(s -> {
                names.add(s.split(":")[0]);
                numbers.add(Integer.parseInt((s.split(":"))[1].trim()));
            });
        }

        IntStream.range(0, Math.min(names.size(), numbers.size()))
                .mapToObj(i -> names.get(i) + ":" + numbers.get(i))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

*Output:*

```
Telur Dadar:40
Maggi Goreng:50
```

Comment: missing catch statement, and can you do the printing using stream instead of for loop?

Comment: I have putted `throws IOException`. And generally to print it using stream `numbers.stream().forEach(System.out::println);` But here i have two arrays to print together. @DanCiborowski-MSFT

Comment: Here we go The printing using stream instead of for loop. See answer edited ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use a map to remove the arrays. This will auto size based on your data.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication2;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.HashMap; 
import java.util.Map; 
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
/**
 *
 * @author dciborow
 */
public class JavaApplication2 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        String file = "";        
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("test.txt"))) {
            stream.forEach(s -> {
                String[] split = s.split(":");
                map.put(split[0], Integer.parseInt(split[1]));
            });
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        map.keySet().stream().forEach(s -> System.out.println(s + ": " + map.get(s)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short, tested solution using java8

```
Path path = Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("file.txt").toURI());

        Map<String, Integer> collect = Files.lines(path)
                .map(line -> line.split(":"))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(lineArray -> lineArray[0], lineArray -> Integer.parseInt(lineArray[1])));
```

Instead of `Files.lines(path)` you could use any method that provides stream of Strings (lines). `map` operation convert lines to String[] (first item=name, secont item=number). Collect uses toMap collector, that requires two functions- one for key, one for value. Collector uses String[] from previous step.